# How to filter Wordpress posts by year published

Tags: php

I'd like to add a new filter for my Wordpress archives to show posts by year published. I want to get the year from the post_meta. How can I do this without have a specific meta field for this?

Answer (score -1):

Check database if you have year field saved. If yes, then `SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY year DESC`